# Why debuild warns about "ignoring deletion of file"?

Tags: debuild

I want to build package for ppa. I use `debuild -S -sa`. But it ignore deletion of files from old source.Like:

```
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file sonata/rhapsodycovers.py
```

All you can see at [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/631181/)

Why does it happens?

Comment: That file is missing from the .orig.tar.gz archive. Create a new archive with the new contents of the package

Answer (score 3):

This is intentional behaviour: packaging is not supposed to modify the contents of the upstream distributed tarball except in a scripted manner.

If you must remove the file for licensing reasons, you will need to modify the orig.tar.gz directly, and then use this as the basis for your packaging.  In this case, it is common to rename the upstream tarball from e.g. "program-1.2.3.tgz" to "program-1.2.3+ds.orig.tar.gz", with the "ds" indicating that the original source is modified for packaging.

If you are not required to remove the file, but prefer to have it removed such that the build completes successfully, it is recommended to remove it in the clean: rule in debian/rules.  If using debhelper, this is most easily achieved using dh_clean by adding the relative path of the file to debian/clean.  The dh_clean(1) manpage has more information about this tool.